# Checking a value defined in a header from a function in another file

Tags: c++, function, header, boolean

I have a header file (head.h) in which I define the boolean value:

```
bool flag = false;
```

In main.c, I have a function:

```
void WINAPI function (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                      HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                      LPSTR lpszArgument,
                      int nFunsterStil)
{
    if (flag == false)
    {
    //Some action
    flag = true;
    }
}
```

The boolean value 'flag' is not recognised even though main.c starts with the line:

```
#include "head.h"
```

...Why?

Comment: Have you already given flag a value?

Comment: Is that the only content of your header?

Comment: In cases like this, the best thing for you to do is create the smallest actual program that exhibits the problem.  When you post just the code above, it should obviously work (and probably does if you were to test THAT code).  There is probably something else in the REAL code causing the problem you are seeing.  Removing code and testing can help you find it.

Comment: `flag` should be extern anyway.

Comment: @Etienne extern is assumed by default at global (namespace) scope for non-const variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you put `#include "head.h"` at the top of `main.c` (before `#include "stdafx.h"`) and you use precompiled header(at least it's how I'm able to reproduce your issue with Visual Studio). `#include "stdafx.h"` should always go first .

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "not recognized"?  Does it fail to compile saying `flag` isn't defined?

Otherwise, in the code you exhibit, there is a little problem that flag has never been set.

Comment: I've updated the code accordingly, but face the same problem.