# Unable to reference variables... Why?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++

I have a very simple bit of code that won't work, and have no idea why

The following:

```
int flag = 0;
if (flag == 0)
{
    flag = 1;
}
```

Will not compile. It is already a quite complex program, and I am able to do other actions within the program with no problems at all, yet for some reason I can't reference a variable I have just created. The variable name is unique, and the application is a Windows app including windows.h. It is written in C, and up until now I have not attempted to create my own variables.

I can't publish the full code here, least of all because there's pages of it, but can anyone speculate as to why it can't compile? I am using Visual C++ and have the following errors:

```
syntax error : missing ';' before 'type' (this applies to line 1)
'flag' : undeclared identifier (line 2)
'flag' : undeclared identifier (line 4)
```

I have tried using bool as well, with 'true' and 'false' in place. I am relatively new to C++. Note that the code compiles fine without it here at all. It comes immediately after a previous action within a larger 'if' statement, of which this is a part. I have successfully added other nested if statements in the exact same place as this. Taking it outside the if statement entirely makes no difference. Putting it all right at the top of my main.c file, just after the #includes, makes no difference. Removing it completely means the program compiles absolutely fine. The problem seems to lie with defining the variable.

Comment: You created "a quite complex program" without ever attempting to declare your own variables?!? How is that even possible?

Comment: It seems, that before your first line, an ';' is missing. So the error is obviously not in the lines you have shown.

Comment: This is all in one file? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002579/checking-a-value-defined-in-a-header-from-a-function-in-another-file

Comment: I didn't create the program, I am modifying one. The line before has a semicolon.

Comment: does renaming flag something else make a difference?

Comment: @Matt: May we see the line before it?

Comment: Tried renaming it, and it doesn't matter which line comes before, I have even put it at the start of the file

Comment: @Bart, yes it's the same program but I'm trying different approaches. I have no idea why it won't work!

Comment: You're giving us very little to go on in both this and your previous question. Any chance you could simplify it to a minimal example of complete code that doesn't work and post it online somewhere? Codepad or something similar?

Comment: It turns out I can't use bool. I guess I was porting stuff from VisualBasic? Anyway, switched to int and placed the definition at the beginning of the function, and this seems to have worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Matt: To use bool, you probably need to `#include <stdbool.h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you compile it to `C` language. You need to declare the variable at the beginning of the block:

```
// beginning of block
int flag=0;
//Some code
if (flag == 0)
{
    flag = 1;
}
```

Comment: This is the problem (rather the solution) - MSVC's C mode doesn't support declarations mixed with statements (it's a C90 compiler).  You can do what MByd suggests or wrap the construct in its own block.

Answer (score 1):

are you missing a ; at the end of the preceding line?

Comment: Nope, it's there as it ought to be

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me, as if the line before the variable declaration has not been finished with a `;`. Check this line for the missing semicolon.